# Using TFS2010 client in a 64-bit only IIS process

Tags: tfs, 32bit-64bit, tfs-sdk

I'm finding conflicting information regarding the TFS 2010 Client assemblies.  I wish to connect to a TFS 2010 server from an ASP.Net application running on IIS 7.5 in a 64-bit only application pool.

I x-copied all the TFS client assemblies into the bin folder of my web application (to avoid having to install the TFS client onto the web server) - but get a bad image format exception from the following assemblies:

- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Cache.dll
- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.RuleEngine.dll
- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.DataStore.dll

They all appear to be 32bit only assemblies.

Is there a way to work around this, or does the application pool have to be enabled for 32bit applications, before you can use the TFS 2010 client assemblies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See my blog post on [Installing Just the Server Components of TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jimlamb/installing-just-the-server-components-of-tfs-2010). That will let you get the 64-bit components you need onto your web server.

Comment: Could you explain how the install will let the code execute the dll without having to enable the the 32 bit on IIS?